# Error while install scss-lint on Visual Studio Code

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, rubygems, mamp

I am trying to install gem **scss-lint** and get the following message error:

`gem install scss_lint`

> ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'scss_lint' (>= 0), here is why:
>             Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert protocol version (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

I have tryed the following command
`gem source -a https://rubygems.org/` following an issue reported on **their [GitHub](https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/issues/320)** but I still have another error message:

> YAML safe loading is not available. Please upgrade psych to a version that supports safe loading (>= 2.0).

*(I am working on MAC OSX if this may help)*

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue. Take a look at these links for more info: https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88
https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1050

Short term workaround is using this source: 'http://rubygems.org'